# Typescript: How to get all property decorators from only the class type?

Tags: typescript, reflection, typescript-decorator

```
const metadataKey = "metadataKey";
class User
{
    @Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, 1)
    name: string;
    @Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, 2)
    age: number;
}

getPropertyDecorators(User); // I hope it can return [1, 2]
```

I hope the function getPropertyDecorators doesn't need to create an instance of User.

Answer (score 5):

There's no built-in functionality in reflect-metadata to do this.  You can build something like this yourself by creating your own property decorator *using* reflect-metadata, by storing the list of property keys on the class's prototype and using that later.  For example:

```
function myPropertyDecorator(
  metadataKey: string,
  metadataValue: any
): PropertyDecorator {
  return function(ctorPrototype: any, propertyKey: string): void {
    // original functionality
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      "data:" + metadataKey,
      metadataValue,
      ctorPrototype,
      propertyKey
    );

    // new functionality
    let propertyKeys =
      Reflect.getOwnMetadata("keys:" + metadataKey, ctorPrototype) ||
      (Reflect.getMetadata("keys:" + metadataKey, ctorPrototype) || []).slice(
        0
      );
    Reflect.defineMetadata("keys:" + metadataKey, propertyKeys, ctorPrototype);

    // record new property key
    propertyKeys.push(propertyKey);
  };
}
```

And then you can still get the metadata given the property key:

```
function getMyPropertyDecorator(
  ctor: { prototype: any },
  metadataKey: string,
  propertyKey: string
) {
  return Reflect.getMetadata(
    "data:" + metadataKey,
    ctor.prototype,
    propertyKey
  );
}
```

As well as enumerate all the property keys for which you stored metadata:

```
function getMyPropertyDecoratorPropertyKeys(
  ctor: { prototype: any },
  metadataKey: string
) {
  return (Reflect.getMetadata("keys:" + metadataKey, ctor.prototype) ||
    []) as string[];
}
```

And even get an object whose keys are those property keys and whose values are the metadata values:

```
function getMyPropertyDecorators(
  ctor: { prototype: any },
  metadataKey: string
) {
  const ret: Record<string, any> = {};
  for (let propertyKey of getMyPropertyDecoratorPropertyKeys(
    ctor,
    metadataKey
  )) {
    ret[propertyKey] = getMyPropertyDecorator(ctor, metadataKey, propertyKey);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This last one gives you enough to do what you want:

```
const metadataKey = "metadataKey";
class User {
  @myPropertyDecorator(metadataKey, 1)
  name: string = "1";
  @myPropertyDecorator(metadataKey, 2)
  age: number = 3;
}

console.log(getMyPropertyDecorators(User, metadataKey)); // {name: 1, age: 2}
```

And if you want a dedicated function to pull out the values into an array (although I don't know how you'd ensure the ordering):

```
function getMyPropertyDecoratorValues(
  ctor: { prototype: any },
  metadataKey: string
) {
  const myPropertyDecorators = getMyPropertyDecorators(ctor, metadataKey);
  return Object.keys(myPropertyDecorators).map(
    propertyKey => myPropertyDecorators[propertyKey]
  );
}


console.log(getMyPropertyDecoratorValues(User, metadataKey)); // [1, 2]
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enumerate-property-decorators-workaround)